# How to install mongodb 3.x in debian jessie (8)?. mongodb web only supports wheezy

Tags: debian, mongodb

I want to install mongodb in debian jessie, but debian repo only has mongodb 2.4 and I need mongodb 3.x.

Mongodb web page instructions for installing latest mongodb in debian only supports [wheezy](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/).

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Can I install it this way despite being for wheezy or would it be better to install it from the tar.gz and deal with unmet dependencies by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can follow the instructions in the [MongoDB official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

- first, import the [MongoDB public GPG Key](https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc?_ga=1.177114469.1586560360.1469539120)

  ```
  sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
  ```
- add a `source.list` configuration file

**Debian 7 (wheezy)**

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

**Debian 8 (jessie)**

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

- reload aptitude cache

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- and finally install the desired version of MongoDB

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.2.10 mongodb-org-server=3.2.10 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.10 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.10 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.10
  ```

Comment: Sadly there are no stretch packages. How can I install mongodb 3.4 on debian 9 (stretch)?

Answer (score 1):

Install the version 2.4 by using the command `apt-get install mongodb` and after that use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.1 mongodb-org-server=3.0.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.1
```

worked for me now i have mongodb 3.0.1 in debian jessie 8.4

Comment: Able to install 2.4 with apt-get install mongodb, and than when I executed sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.0.1 mongodb-org-server=3.0.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.0.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.0.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.0.1 it says "unable to locate package"